# ruby to android 3DES encryption - pad block corrupted

Tags: java, android, ruby, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a string in ruby and descrypt in Android.  I'm pretty unfamiliar with ciphering, but I've done some reading and I think I'm close to getting to work.  however, I'm still getting an error on the Android side that I just do not understand how to fix.  I understand what padding is and that it's not correct, but what do I need to change to make this work?   My ruby and java code are below.  Thank you!!!

Ruby:

```
shared_key = "123456789012345678901234"      
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("des3")
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = shared_key
ciphertext = cipher.update(secret)
ciphertext << cipher.final
Rails.logger.debug(ciphertext);

encrypted_secret = Base64.encode64(ciphertext)
Rails.logger.debug(encrypted_secret);
render json: { 'token' => token, 'secret' => encrypted_secret }, status: :ok
```

Java:

```
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(SHARED_DECRYPTION_KEY.getBytes("UTF8"), "DESede");
    byte[] encryptedSecretBytes = Base64.decode(secret);     
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede"); // cipher is not thread safe
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] plainTextSecretBytes = (cipher.doFinal(encryptedSecretBytes));
    String decryptedSecret = Base64.encodeBytes(plainTextSecretBytes);
```

and the exception I get in Android:

```
05-14 19:03:11.500: W/System.err(22175): javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted
05-14 19:03:11.500: W/System.err(22175):    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:709)
05-14 19:03:11.500: W/System.err(22175):    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1111)
05-14 19:03:11.500: W/System.err(22175):    at com.cdlcollege.saas.Credentials.storeServerAccessCredentials(Credentials.java:85)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pad block corrupted means the wrong key was used to decrypt or the data was altered between encryption and decryption.

If I had to guess, I suspect you are creating a key in the wrong manner. Instead of calling `getBytes()`, I'm guessing you should have done a hex conversion.

See [Convert hex string to byte []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714616/convert-hex-string-to-byte) for example Android code for performing this task.

---

Side note: don't just specify `"DESede"` for a cipher. Specify the mode and padding as well. E.g. `"DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`. That ensures you get exactly what you want, rather than crypto provider defaults (which may vary across phones).

Comment: ok interesting i'll check on these and see where it gets me.  thanks for the pointers.

Comment: thanks for the help, it definitely set me on the right track.  I also found that this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266556/encrypt-in-ruby-and-decrypt-in-java-why-is-it-not-working is close to a duplicate, and contains some code that helped me get this working with AES encryption.

Comment: @deepwinter What was the root cause of the problem?

Comment: i fixed the pad block corrupted issue by doing a Base64.decode on the key rather than getBytes().  i then had problems setting key which was the correct length, but once I followed the AES example (and AES is recommended anyway) i figure most things out.  the main thing with this is, as you say, making sure you convert your text strings and other variables to bytes in a consistent way.