# How to implement AES encryption in Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, aes

guys

Here's a snippet of code of Java about AES encrypt:

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.exceptions.Base64DecodingException;
import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

...

public static String encrypt(String content, String password) {  
    try {             
            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(password.getBytes()));

            SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); 
            byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8"); 
            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);                   
            return Base64.encode(result);  
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
    }
    return null;  
}
```

Now I try to implement it in Ruby(not work):

```
def self.aes128_encrypt(password, content)
  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-128-ECB')
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = password
  result = cipher.update(content) + cipher.final
  Base64.encode64(result).chomp
end
```

After some research, I think the problem is the cipher#key: In Java, it's generate by securerandom with password as seed, But in Ruby, I use the password directly.

So I want to generate key like Java. But I find the random number generator used by Java is NativePRNG, which I do not find the same implementation so far.

Now, I want to ask help from guys familiar with Ruby and Java:

**How can I implement the same AES encrypt in Ruby?
Or how to generate random string in Ruby with NativePRNG.**

Any advice is welcome, and Thank you very much for each reply.

Comment: This is not possible. On many machines, NativePRNG algorithm is not pseudorandom, but truly random (using `/dev/random`, which is populated from hardware-related events such as keyboard event timings, microphone input noise...) By definition, you cannot replicate a true random number generator. Your best bet is to rewrite your Java code to hash secret key in a predictable way, such as PBKDF2 (as shown in Rubydoc example [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS5.html#module-OpenSSL::PKCS5-label-Generating+a+128+bit+key+for+a+Cipher+-28e.g.+AES-29)).

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266556/encrypt-in-ruby-and-decrypt-in-java-why-is-it-not-working) and the accompanying answer show you an example of this.

Comment: @Amadan As I understand it, any random value generated in a computer will always be pseudo-random, even if it's done in a secure way with a high entropy source. Why do you claim that "NativePRNG algorithm is not pseudorandom, but truly random"? Are you 100% sure that statement is 100% accurate?

Comment: @Amadan Yes, I have same question with ray. since I know little about random number generator, but I find the implemention is so common in basic java code(https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=AES%2CCipher%2CSecureRandom+in%3Afile++language%3AJava&type=Code&ref=searchresults). So maybe it's a standard implemention in Java world.

Comment: Not 100% accurate, but not too inaccurate either. Where available, [`/dev/random`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) is generated from an entropy pool that is gathered from [outside the computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator#Using_observed_events), by exploiting user input, microphone input, hard drive input and other non-predictable analog events. Not all systems have this capability, but where it exists, [Java NativePRNG will use it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/security/provider/NativePRNG.java).

Comment: Generation of numbers from this entropy pool is, technically, pseudorandom; but it is still not reproducible (simply because you cannot fill the entropy pool with the exactly same analog events). `SecureRandom` uses this source when available; when not, it uses [another algorithm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SecureRandomImp). Unless you select the algorithm yourself, the system will select an algorithm for you depending on the current capabilities - i.e. even the Java code will not behave the same way if you port it to different machines.

Comment: @Amadan You are right, I think It's bad idea with random number for key.